# Looking to send the value of a cell at the end of a string to command prompt to run VNC

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vnc

I'm wanting to send the value of a specific cell to the end of a string, then send that to command prompt.

For example this is what I have working.

```
Sub VNCTest()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe 192.168.0.2"
    RetVal = Shell(txt)
End Sub
```

I'm able to explicitly say which IP to send to VNC to launch the program, however I'm wanting to achieve something like this.

```
Sub VNCTest()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe " & This.Worksheet(Sheet1)TEXT(Q5)
    RetVal = Shell(txt)
End Sub
```

To send the VNC viewer the value of cell Q5 where I could store the IP address.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please edit following code for your needs:

```vb
Sub VNCTest()
    Dim strCmd As String
    Dim strIp As String

    strIp = Range("Q5").Value
 
    strCmd = "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe " & strIp
    '--- button OK for test case only
    MsgBox strCmd, vbOKOnly
    '--- action
    RetVal = Shell(strCmd)
End Sub
```

The resulting MsgBox looks like

[image]